# Circular progress bar text

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I'm using [this library](https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress)
and I'm using "DonutProgress".
How do i change text inside the circle, i have a value double average in my code and i want to show that inside the circle instead of that progress (progress is integer) with percentage.
For example i set if average is greater than 4.5, set progress at 100%, and what happens is, that blue circle around goes to the end and text inside circle says 100%.
I want to show the actual average instead of 100% without changing that blue circle around.
Also is it possible to set specific colors, for example if progress is at 20% or less, to use red color instead of blue, if it's between 20% and 40% use green, etc..?

Answer (score 0):

The source class for DonutProgress is located [here](https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/github/lzyzsd/circleprogress/DonutProgress.java), and after importing it, you could simply add your own code to change the class to fit your needs.

EDIT: For the colors of the progress circle, you can see there are multiple colors defined at the top of the class, as constants. They are in rgb format, so to change them to your desired color, [a site like this one](http://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.htm) would be a great resource.

Comment: i tried doing that but it's not working, i guess i'm not experienced enough, can you help?

Comment: thanks for that, but what about changing the text?
i just tried changing that "suffix = "%"" to "suffix = "test"" and it was still %

Comment: now i changed the colors as well, like this:
private final int default_finished_color = Color.rgb(34, 255, 0);
    private final int default_unfinished_color = Color.rgb(255, 17, 0);

first one should be green and second one red, but it's still the same though, gray and blue

Comment: it seems like it's not the source class, cuz even when i removed it completely and synced my app, everything was still working like before

Comment: ok, i created the new colors throug xml file, still can't change the text though

Comment: did i put it in the proper folder? it's in the app\libs right now

Comment: I believe that is the correct folder; it appears that the text is stored in separate xml files, so you would likely have to edit them in order to see a change. Such as here, on line 40 of the file: `suffixText = attributes.getString(R.styleable.DonutProgress_donut_suffix_text);
`

Comment: i removed the suffix % by using "custom:donut_suffix_text=""" in my activity's xml, but i still can't user double value as progress value even though i changed int progress to double progress in DonutProgress.java

Comment: whatever i do to DonutProgress.java it doesn't affect the app, very strange